# Stepping through expression trees (inspecting parameter values, etc)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, expression

I'm looking for a way to inspect the values of parameters (and potentially variables, etc.) within a .Net Expression Tree.

I can do this if I have a block in my lambda (non-expression), i.e.:

```
// Define string list
List<string> strs = new List<string>(new[] { "one", "two", "three" });

// Filter strings
string[] filtered = strs.Where(s => {
    return s.Length == 5 ||  s.StartsWith("o"); // Can set a breakpoint here
}).ToArray();
```

However, I cannot do it when I'm using an expression that is compatible with a SQL question (i.e. Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities which mandates non-block statements):

```
MyContext ctx = new MyContext();

// Filter strings
IQueryable<project> projects = ctx.projects.Where(p => 
    p.Name.Length == 5 ||  p.Name.StartsWith("o"); // CANNOT set a breakpoint here
).ToArray();
```

#### Why am I asking this?

I'm experiencing a Null reference exception that is occurring several levels deep within my expression tree and given that I cannot break on the statements, I cannot inspect the values of the parameters.

Comment: Are you sure that semi colon is in the right place? And you will need to have a block to be able to insert a breakpoint there, that's just a limitation we have I believe..

Comment: CLR will convert `linq` query to `sql` script, you can check the sql script when do searching

Comment: @Tim.Tang, I understand that the statement will be converted to SQL... UNLESS you have an issue with your expression. I'm encountering a null reference exception that I cannot figure out with ease as the issue is  multiple levels deep within nested lambdas

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the value of an Expression in the debugger before using it.
I dont quiet see how the sample code is an Expression. Looks more like straight Linq and lambdas.

Anyway.. You can see the Expression tree in debugger.

```
   public virtual TPoco Get(Expression<Func<TPoco, bool>> predicate) {
        try {
            var resultEntity = AllQ().FirstOrDefault(predicate);  //<<<<< Breakpoint, predicate can be viewed
            return resultEntity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // your error handling             
            return null;
        }
    }


    // call with 
    var rep = new Rep<Table>();
    var row = rep.Get(t=>t.StartsWith("o" );
```

be aware of the Linq restrictions in Linq to entities 
         [Supported Linq methods in EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550)

Comment: Phil, you are correct, it is not an expression and I should make that more clear as to remove confusion.